# C Shell (cpp.sh, browser based compiler) is running a program Visual Studio won't

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, conditional-operator

so I am working on a c++ program for a school project.

I used a bunch of conditional operators (I like the shorthand) and it runs just fine on C Shell (this is the link. the program works just fine there... http://cpp.sh/7fsj ) but it wont run on Visual Studio C++ and I was curious if there was some sort of error in my code...

my program is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter an angle and I will tell you which quadrant it is in.\n\n\n";
double angle;
cin >> angle;
cout << endl;
bool first, second, third, fourth, xaxis, yaxis, nxaxis, nyaxis;


if (angle < 0 || angle > 360)
    cout << "Invalid input.";
else
{
(angle > 0 && angle < 90 ? first = true : first = false);
(first == true ? cout << "The angle you entered is in the first quadrant.\n\n" : cout << "");
(angle > 90 && angle < 180 ? second = true : second = false);
(second == true ? cout << "The angle you entered is in the second quadrant.\n\n" : cout << "");
(angle > 180 && angle < 270 ? third = true : third = false);
(third == true ? cout << "The angle you entered is in the third quadrant.\n\n" : cout << "");
(angle > 270 && angle < 360 ? fourth = true : fourth = false);
(fourth == true ? cout << "The angle you entered is in the fourth quadrant.\n\n" : cout << "");
(angle == 0 || angle == 360 ? nxaxis = true : nxaxis = false);
(angle == 180 ? xaxis = true : xaxis = false);
(nxaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the negative portion of the x axis.\n\n" : "");
(xaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the positive portion of the x axis.\n\n" : "");
(angle == 90 ? yaxis = true : yaxis = false);
(angle == 270 ? nyaxis = true : nyaxis = false);
(yaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the positive portion of the y axis.\n\n" : "");
(nyaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the negative portion of the y axis.\n\n" : "");
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

It runs there but not in VS

I can't find any logical errors or reasons for an error but it keeps saying this

```
"1>------ Build started: Project: lab-projects, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  project.cpp
1>c:\users\wishi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab-projects\lab-projects\project.cpp(179): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\wishi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab-projects\lab-projects\project.cpp(180): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\wishi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab-projects\lab-projects\project.cpp(183): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>c:\users\wishi\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\lab-projects\lab-projects\project.cpp(184): error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="
```

This is a beginning programming class so I have no idea what this means.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

You're abusing the ternary operator, the usual and more readable way of using it is like this:

```
xaxis = angle == 180 ? true : false;
```

You're using it like a full blown control structure, instead of `if`s.

Now the errors that you're getting make sens. One of the rules regarding the ternary operator says that both expressions after the `?` must have the same type. On this line for example:

```
(nxaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the negative portion of the x axis.\n\n" : "");
```

the first expression (`cout << "..."`) is an `ostream` and the second one (`""`) is a `const char *`. That's what the error message is trying to tell you, that it's trying to convert the second expression to an `ostream` to match the type of the first one.

To fix it, you can either write the expression as you did in the previous lines, even though it's ugly:

```
(nxaxis == true ? cout << "This angle lies on the negative portion of the x axis.\n\n" : cout << "");
```

Or you can write it like this instead:

```
cout << (nxaxis ? "This angle ..." : "");
```

Or even better:

```
if (nxaxis)
{
    cout << "This angle ...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Please enter an angle and I will tell you which quadrant it is in.\n";
  double angle;
  cin >> angle;

  int quadrant = -1;
  if (angle >= 0 && angle < 90) {
    quadrant = 1;
    cout << "The angle you entered is in the first quadrant.\n";
  } else if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180) {
    quadrant = 2;
    cout << "The angle you entered is in the second quadrant.\n";
  } ...
  } else {
    cout << "Illegal value!\n";
    ...
  }

  cin.ignore();
  return 0;
}
```